# How do you get the last record generated in a recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am using recursive in sql 2014 in below code.

```
 WITH products AS 
(
 SELECT 
     prd.productID, 
     prd.MainproductID,
     prc.Price,Level = 0, 
     Row_ID = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prd.productID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
     Level2 = CAST(prd.productID AS VarChar(Max))  
FROM  
  PrdTable prd 
INNER JOIN prd_priceList (NOLOCK) prc ON prd.productID= prc.productID  
WHERE prd.MainproductID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    prd.productID, 
    prd.MainproductID,
    prc.Price,Level +1,
    prcRec.Row_ID + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prd.MainproductID ORDER BY prd.productID) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
    Level2 = CAST(prcRec.productID AS VarChar(Max))   + ', ' + prcRec.Level2 
FROM  
  products prcRec 
INNER JOIN PrdTable prd ON prcRec.productID= prd.MainproductID
INNER JOIN prd_priceList (NOLOCK) prc ON prd.productID= prc.productID   

 )  
select  
   productID  , 
   MainproductID , 
   Level,
   Row_ID,
   Level2 
from prodproductsucts
```

And this return like result in attachment screenshot. I want only select bottom line of each level.If doesn't have child then will select its. But if has child then will go to latest level and pick latest one. I alsa paint yellow rows which i need to select in screenshot.
[image: result 's here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements...

In the final query just add the following `WHERE`

```
... Where productID not in (Select Distinct ISNULL(MainProductID,-999) From products)
```

Comment: I added ISNULL statement and then it worked for this sample. I will make a test with whole data and accept it as answer if works.                                 `... Where productID not in (Select Distinct ISNULL(MainProductID ,-999) From products)`